# Angular/Breeze Login implementation

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, breeze, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a SPA app that uses Angular and Breeze, I need to implement the login functionality and I am new to Angular/Breeze. My architecture/code structure is as mentioned below:

> login.html --> login.js -->datacontext/Service.js--->entityManagerFactory-->breezecontroller.cs -->repository->dbcontext-->database.

I am facing following challenges:

1. I am unable to show the login page as default, I am always getting Dashboard as a default page. I am looking for where I can route to login page.
   2.breezecontroller -- This is inside controller, do I need to write my login method here?

All in all, I am looking for a complete login functionality implementation which following my architecture/code structure.

Comment: Big question. Glad someone answered. I'll just add that **I would not put the login in a breeze controller**. Authentication and Authorization are separate concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a description of an approach that can be used in an Angular-based SPA. This particular example uses token-based OAuth authentication, but could be adapted to other authentication schemes. It is loosely based on the approach described at [Authentication in AngularJS (or similar) based application](http://espeo.pl/authentication-in-angularjs-application/)

Some highlights are:

- Authentication is managed through an `auth` service.
- HTTP requests are intercepted, and:

  - When a 401 (access denied) error is detected and no user is logged in, an `auth:login` event is emitted (note - not broadcasted) on `$rootScope`
  - If a 401 error is detected while a user is logged in and an OAuth refresh token is available, an attempt is made to get a new access token based on the refresh token. An `auth:login` event is only emitted if the token cannot be refreshed.
  - Once a user has logged in, an `Authorization` header containing the user's access token is inserted onto each HTTP request so that the server can authenticate the user.
- The application should watch for `auth:login` events and prompt the user for credentials. (I use an [Angular-UI Bootstrap modal dialog](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for doing this.) Once credentials have been provided, the `auth` service's `login` function must be called to complete the login. After `login` is called, all pending HTTP requests that initially failed with a 401 error are retried. Alternatively, the `auth` service's `loginCancelled` function can be called to cancel the login, which will reject all pending HTTP requests.

  For example:

```
angular.module('app', ['auth'])
.run(['$rootScope', 'auth', function ($rootScope,  auth) {
    $rootScope.$on(auth.options.loginRequiredEvent, function (event, details) {
        // Display login dialog here, which will ultimately
        // call `auth.login` or `auth.loginCancelled`
    });

    auth.restoreAuthDataFromStorage();
}]);
```

Here is an example of calling `auth.login` once the user has provided credentials:

```
auth.login(userName, password, isPersistent)
    .success(function () {
        // Dismiss login dialog here
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
        if (status === 401 || (data && data.error === 'invalid_grant')) {
            failureMessage = 'Log in failed: Bad username or password';
        } else {
            failureMessage = 'Log in failed: Unexpected error';
        }
    });
```

- Details of the logged in user are stored in `window.sessionStorage` or `window.localStorage` (based on whether a persistent login has been requested) to be able to be accessed across page loads.

Finally, here is the `auth` service itself.

```
var module = angular.module('auth');

module.provider('auth', function () {
    var authOptions = {
        tokenUrl: '/OAuthToken',
        loginRequiredEvent: 'auth:loginRequired',
        logoffEvent: 'auth:logoff',
        loginEvent: 'auth:login',
        authTokenKey: 'auth:accessToken'
    };

    this.config = function (options) {
        angular.extend(authOptions, options);
    };

    // Get the auth service
    this.$get = ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {
        var authData = {
            // Filled as follows when authenticated:
            // currentUserName: '...',
            // accessToken: '...',
            // refreshToken: '...',
        };

        var httpRequestsPendingAuth = new HttpRequestsPendingAuthQueue();

        // Public service API
        return {
            login: login,
            refreshAccessToken: refreshAccessToken,
            loginCancelled: loginCancelled,
            logoff: logoff,
            currentUserName: function () { return authData.currentUserName; },
            isAuthenticated: function () { return !!authData.accessToken; },
            getAccessToken: function () { return authData.accessToken; },
            restoreAuthDataFromStorage: restoreAuthDataFromStorage,
            _httpRequestsPendingAuth: httpRequestsPendingAuth,
            options: authOptions,
        };

        function isAuthenticated() {
            return !!authData.accessToken;
        };

        function restoreAuthDataFromStorage() {
            // Would be better to use an Angular service to access local storage
            var dataJson = window.sessionStorage.getItem(authOptions.authTokenKey) || window.localStorage.getItem(authOptions.authTokenKey);

            authData = (dataJson ? JSON.parse(dataJson) : {});
        }

        function accessTokenObtained(data) {
            if (!data || !data.access_token) {
                throw new Error('No token data returned');
            }

            angular.extend(authData, {
                accessToken: data.access_token,
                refreshToken: data.refresh_token
            });

            // Would be better to use an Angular service to access local storage
            var storage = (authData.isPersistent ? window.localStorage : window.sessionStorage);
            storage.setItem(authOptions.authTokenKey, JSON.stringify(authData));

            httpRequestsPendingAuth.retryAll($http);
        }

        function login(userName, password, isPersistent) {
            // Data for obtaining token must be provided in a content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            var data = 'grant_type=password&username=' + encodeURIComponent(userName) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password);

            return $http
                .post(authOptions.tokenUrl, data, { ignoreAuthFailure: true })
                .success(function (data) {
                    authData = {
                        currentUserName: userName,
                        isPersistent: isPersistent
                    };

                    accessTokenObtained(data);

                    $rootScope.$emit(authOptions.loginEvent);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    logoff();
                });
        }

        function refreshAccessToken() {
            if (!authData.refreshToken) {
                logoff();
                return $q.reject('No refresh token available');
            }

            // Data for obtaining token must be provided in a content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            var data = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + encodeURIComponent(authData.refreshToken);

            return $http
                .post(authOptions.tokenUrl, data, { ignoreAuthFailure: true })
                .success(function (data) { accessTokenObtained(data); })
                .error(function () { logoff(); });
        }

        function loginCancelled() {
            httpRequestsPendingAuth.rejectAll();
        }

        function logoff() {
            // Would be better to use an Angular service to access local storage
            window.sessionStorage.removeItem(authOptions.authTokenKey);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(authOptions.authTokenKey);

            if (isAuthenticated()) {
                authData = {};

                $rootScope.$emit(authOptions.logoffEvent);
            }
        }

        // Class implementing a queue of HTTP requests pending authorization
        function HttpRequestsPendingAuthQueue() {
            var q = [];

            this.append = function (rejection, deferred) {
                q.push({ rejection: rejection, deferred: deferred });
            };

            this.rejectAll = function () {
                while (q.length > 0) {
                    var r = q.shift();
                    r.deferred.reject(r.rejection);
                }
            };

            this.retryAll = function ($http) {
                while (q.length > 0) {
                    var r = q.shift();
                    retryRequest($http, r.rejection.config, r.deferred);
                }
            };

            function retryRequest($http, config, deferred) {
                var configToUse = angular.extend(config, { ignoreAuthFailure: true });

                $http(configToUse)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    }, function (response) {
                        deferred.reject(response);
                    });
            }
        }
    }];
});

module.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$injector', '$rootScope', '$q', function ($injector, $rootScope, $q) {
        var auth;

        return {
            // Insert an "Authorization: Bearer <token>" header on each HTTP request
            request: function (config) {
                auth = auth || $injector.get('auth');

                var token = auth.getAccessToken();
                if (token) {
                    config.headers = config.headers || {};
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
                }

                return config;
            },

            // Raise a "login required" event upon "401 access denied" responses on HTTP requests
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 401 && !rejection.config.ignoreAuthFailure) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                    auth = auth || $injector.get('auth');

                    auth._httpRequestsPendingAuth.append(rejection, deferred);

                    if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                        auth.refreshAccessToken().then(null, function () {
                            $rootScope.$emit(auth.options.loginRequiredEvent, { message: 'Login session has timed out. Please log in again.' });
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Not currently logged in and a request for a protected resource has been made: ask for a login
                        $rootScope.$emit(auth.options.loginRequiredEvent, { rejection: rejection });
                    }

                    return deferred.promise;
                }

                // otherwise, default behaviour
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
}]);
```